# Como incluir uma coluna que demonstre imagem dinamicamente em um GridView

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, vb.net, gridview

Estou gerando um relatório e exportando para Excel, porém como a maioria dos relatórios a quantidade de colunas é dinâmica e estou montando o gridview dinamicamente. Estou necessitando demonstrar uma coluna que exiba imagens na tabela, então estou incluindo esta coluna após ter o resultado da minha consulta, até ai tudo bem, porém quando dou o databind() essa coluna que está no datasource do gridview não é incluindo na estrutura de controle do gridview, assim não renderizando e não demonstrando na planilha. Sabendo-se que guardo as imagens no banco em um array de bytes. Segue o trecho do meu código abaixo. Por favor me ajudem!

```
  Dim grid As New GridView

        If posicaoLogo = -1 Then

            'Remove coluna identificador
            dataTable.Columns.RemoveAt(0)

            grid.DataSource = New DataView(dataTable)
            grid.DataBind()
        Else
            Dim testeGrid As DataView = New DataView(dataTable)

            'Tratamento Para inclusão da coluna tipo byte() devido a logomarca
            Dim row As DataRow
            Dim column As DataColumn
            ReDim listaLogo(0)
            ReDim listaIdentificadorMarca(0)

            i = 0
            For Each row In testeGrid.Table.Rows
                ReDim Preserve listaLogo(i)
                ReDim Preserve listaIdentificadorMarca(i)
                For Each column In testeGrid.Table.Columns
                    If column.ToString = "Identificador" Then
                        listaIdentificadorMarca(i) = row(column).ToString
                    End If
                    If column.ToString = "Logo" Then
                        If row(column).ToString = "SIM" Then
                            listaLogo(i) = "1"
                        Else
                            listaLogo(i) = "0"
                        End If
                    End If
                Next column
                i = i + 1
            Next row

            Dim dtcloned As Data.DataTable = testeGrid.Table.Clone
            Dim logomarcaMarca As DataColumn = New DataColumn("Logomarca")

            logomarcaMarca.DataType = GetType(System.Byte())

            dtcloned.Columns.Add(logomarcaMarca)

            i = 0
            Dim dtMarca As Data.DataTable = testeGrid.Table.Copy
            Dim logomarcaMarcaAux As DataColumn = New DataColumn("Logomarca")

            logomarcaMarcaAux.DataType = GetType(System.Byte())

            dtMarca.Columns.Add(logomarcaMarcaAux)
            For Each rowData As DataRow In dtMarca.Rows
                If listaLogo(i) = "1" Then
                    marca.identificador = listaIdentificadorMarca(i)
                    marca = marca.getImagem
                    rowData.SetField(dtMarca.Columns(dtMarca.Columns.Count - 1), marca.imagem)


                    dtcloned.ImportRow(rowData)
                Else
                    dtcloned.ImportRow(rowData)
                End If
                i = i + 1
            Next

            'Remove coluna de controle
            dtcloned.Columns.RemoveAt(dtMarca.Columns.Count - 2)

            'Remove coluna identificador
            dtcloned.Columns.RemoveAt(0)

            Dim dataviewMarcaAux As New DataView(dtcloned)
            grid.DataSource = dataviewMarcaAux


            grid.DataBind()
        End If
```

Comment: Me tira uma dúvida, é possível mesmo exibir uma imagem apenas passando o array de bytes direto para logomarcaMarca e adicionando a coluna? Esse modelo funciona mesmo? Veja esse post do Stack sobre isso: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17351045/showing-image-in-gridview-from-byte-array

Comment: Até agora não consegui obter êxito passando um array de bytes e nem a própria imagem, convertendo o array para System.Drawing.Image. Estou tentando vasculhar nos fóruns algum modo, porém n achei nada que vinhesse a calhar.

Comment: vou tentar reproduzir seu exemplo e comento aqui

Comment: Obrigado! No aguardo do seu comentário.

Answer (score 1):

Perdão a demora @user2992172, segue a melhor solução encontrada seguindo seu exemplo:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        //Cria primeiras colunas
        dt.Columns.AddRange(new DataColumn[4] { new DataColumn("Id", typeof(int)),
                            new DataColumn("Name", typeof(string)),
                            new DataColumn("Country",typeof(string)), new DataColumn("logo",typeof(string)) });

        //Adiciona coluna com o logo       
        DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
        dr["Id"] = "5";
        dr["Name"] = "Felipe";
        dr["Country"] = "Brazil";
        dt.Rows.Add(dr);

        GridView1.DataSource = dt;
        GridView1.DataBind();
    }

    protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            Image ibtn = new Image();
            ibtn.ID = "imgPicture";
            e.Row.Cells[3].Controls.Add(ibtn);

            Image imgPicture = (Image)e.Row.FindControl("imgPicture");
            if ((imgPicture != null))
            {
                //Transforma o array de byte em base64 e atribui o controle Image à coluna
                System.Drawing.Image img = System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(@"C:\html5.png");
                byte[] imgArray = imageToByteArray(img);
                string base64String = Convert.ToBase64String(imgArray, 0, imgArray.Length);
                imgPicture.ID = "imgPicture";
                imgPicture.ImageUrl = "data:image/png;base64," + base64String;
            }
        }
    }

    public byte[] imageToByteArray(System.Drawing.Image imageIn)
    {
        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
        imageIn.Save(ms, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
        return ms.ToArray();
    }
```

Tive que fazer em C# mas acredito que a ideia é a mesma e migrar o código é tranquilo. Assim como você não consegui atribuir diretamente o controle no DataTable e passar para o GridView, então usei o RowDataBound para criar o controle na Cell, transformar o array de byte em Base64 e jogar para o atributo ImageUrl do controle Image. O resultado:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Veja que no seu caso você não precisa carregar uma imagem de um arquivo como fiz em FromFile(""), como você já tem um array de bytes você ja vai direto pro método ToBase64String(). No ASPX existe apenas a declaração do grid:

```
 <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" OnRowDataBound="GridView1_RowDataBound"></asp:GridView>
```